# Autocorrect for specific people and the language they use

Tags: autocorrect

I don't think this option exists, but doesn't hurt to ask. And it would be amazing if Apple could implement this option in case it doesn't exist.

I have people that I correspond that speak different languages. It would simply amazing if my devices and apps (Mail, Messages, Skype, etc) would recognize who I am writing to and remember what autocorrect language I had set up for them.

That way, it would always autocorrect the appropriate language without me having to switch it. (On the actual Mac, switching the languages is not even an easy step).

I hope there is some solution in the meantime other than just turning autocorrect off.. :)

Comment: I think he's referring to multiple languages that use the same roman alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

When editing text, right click and choose "Show Spelling and Grammar":

[image: Show spelling and grammar]

Select Automatic by Language:

[image: Automatic by language]

This works for me, I use two languages (English and Italian).

Edit: This is for Spelling and Grammar, the setting for autocorrect is in Keyboard->Text:
[image: Keyboard->Text]

You'll also have to add the languages you will use in the Languge & Region panel of System Preferences.

Comment: Thanks for your response BrethilI 
I think that this was the default setting already. Or is there some check-mark that I need to additionally apply to make this work? 
I have all those fields checked (plus "check grammar with spelling" in your first picture "check grammar" one in your second picture).
How does the set-up actually know that you are in fact using Italian vs. English for different people?

Comment: I simply start typing in Italian/English and the words are recognized from both languages, if I'm typing in English and I suddenly start writing Italian words they get marked as wrong/autocorrected to the closest English word.

Comment: Ah I see, so mixing languages can confuse the system. As sometimes, a few words do get mixed in. So it is important to keep it at one language at a time. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I also just realized that it doesn't have autocorrect for some of the languages that I am using, so it is automatically reverting to English?

Comment: I'd add Languages in the Languge & Region panel of System Preferences

Comment: Great! That was the missing link! Thanks Brethil! :)

Comment: No problem! Please my answer as the correct answer, thanks!

Comment: @user2502562  If you click on the Automatic in system preferences/keyboard/text/spellling, you will see Setup at the bottom of the list.  This will let you select the languages you want the Automatic to apply to.